# access-control-allow-origin happening randomly

Tags: javascript, json, playframework-2.0, cross-domain

I've got a local server : 127.0.0.1:8000 and a website : 127.0.0.1:9000 both running with play2 framework.

I make multiple jquery ajax request on the server to get json data and load graphics with these datas.

The problem is that in a totaly random way, i get an access-control-allow-origin error. I read a lot about access-control-allow-origin, and modified the server's header response this way :

```
Response.ok(Engine.executeQuery(identifier, queryParameters))
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, POST, OPTIONS")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Content-Type, *")
                .build();
```

My ajax calls are made this way:

```
$.ajax({
        url: obj.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain:true,
        success: function (data){
            // load graph
        }
```

I've 10 ajax calls, all made exactly the same way, at the same target url.

The problem is that when I load the page (and execute the ajax calls), some ajax calls works and some don't. If i refresh the page, a different number of calls works. This look realy random to me.

I also noticed that if I specify async:false to the ajax calls, the error is never fired. Of course, I need the calls to be asynchronous (it would have been too easy).

I saw so many posts about this error that I thought I knew everything about it.

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: open developer console, in network tab check headers of all ajax urls whether it contains cors headers. if not, then you have problem in server not in client.

Comment: I just checked, i guess Accept: \*/\* means it's ok right ? So i've trouble server side ?

Comment: You should have "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" this header, "Accept" header is for different purpose. Please check your server side that Allow origin header is not set for all requests so you are getting error

Comment: My response header is ok, all the access-control-allow-* are set and ok, i can see that with the requests who worked. The request header haven't any access-control-allow in it. Should it ?

Comment: request header doesnt need anything for cors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I refactored the server and it works great. 
It seems that it was a thread issue, not safe enough.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Facing the same issue,can you please elaborate the solution.

Comment: Sorry I can't, it was 9 years ago :p I suppose it was a bad design somewhere. Try to go back to the simplest implementation and work your way up until it starts to fail